# How to clone repos inside a directory with their author name with REST API?

Tags: git, github, jq, xargs

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/6ae40d4b39167112c675a8b8d744b93b) `bash` & `jq` script:

```sh
UserName=CHANGEME; \
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000 |\
jq -r '.[]|.clone_url' |\
xargs -L1 git clone
```

It will clone the repos into a directory using the REST API parameter `name` (repo.name). (Default behavior)

I want it to clone the repos into a directory using the REST API parameter `full_name` (since it consists of `repo.owner` and `repo.name`), how do I get around to do that?

---

This is what is created inside my directory:

```
repo.name1
repo.name2
```

This is what I want inside my directory:

```
repo.owner1\repo.name1
repo.owner2\repo.name2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered by Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668899/491657):

> 1. The individual arguments read by xargs should ideally be **quoted**.
> 2. xargs needs to call git clone with **two separate arguments**: the repository URL and the destination directory into which to clone it.

`jq -r '.[] | .html_url, .full_name'` -> `jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ]'`

> 3. Add the `@sh` operator to output a each such array as a line of shell-quoted words

`jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ]'` -> `jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ] | @sh'`

---

> 4. Add `-n 2` so that xargs will call the utility with **two arguments** from its input stream at a time

`xargs git clone` > `xargs -n 2 git clone`

---

> 5. Together:

```sh
curl -s "https://api.github.com/users/$UserName/repos?per_page=1000" |
jq -r '.[] | [ .html_url, .full_name ] | @sh' |
xargs -n 2 git clone
```